# Javascript library dependencies with or without bundling?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, node-modules

I am trying to package a library so that it can be used both as:

```
<script src="myLib.js"/>
```

and

```
mylib = require('myLib')
```

But myLib is dependant on a lot of other libraries, some of which I know the consumer of myLib will already use.

So is it possible to create myLib and use it in either of the ways specified above, without me having to bundle all of my dependency libs into myLib? 
What is the best practice?

Comment: Have a development version and a product version of the js?

Comment: @Icewine Yes, that is a possibility if it can't be solved using only one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this link http://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html which seem to address the issue, by using webpack externals.